# Is it possible to send RingCentral SMS / MMS using multipart/form-data?

Tags: sms, mms, ringcentral

The OpenAPI spec for the Create SMS Message endpoint includes the following request content types:

```
  consumes:
  - application/json
  - multipart/mixed
  - multipart/form-data
```

- https://netstorage.ringcentral.com/dpw/api-reference/specs/rc-platform.yml?v=2019082420190816-0828

I found the SMS / MMS instructions to include a `multipart/mixed` example in the API Reference, but don't see any information on using `multipart/form-data`. I'm specifically interested in sending files.

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/SMS/createSMSMessage

The same API Reference shows support for both `multipart/form-data` and `multipart/mixed` for sending faxes.

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Fax/createFaxMessage

Since both APIs send files and metadata so I'm wondering if the SMS API also supports `multipart/form-data` and, if so, how to send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` can be sent as shown in the following example:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms
Authorization: Bearer <MyToken>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=12345

--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

+16505550101
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

+16505550102
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

+16505550100
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

Hello World
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment" filename="picture.jpg"

content of picture.jpg ...
--12345--
```

This can be done using curl as follows:

```
curl -XPOST https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <MyToken>' \
-F 'to=+16505550101' \
-F 'to=+16505550102' \
-F 'from=+16505550100' \
-F 'text=Hello World' \
-F 'attachment=@picture.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not appear so.

The example you'd linked for the SMS message uses `multipart/mixed` to separate the API call itself (which is in turn sent as `application/json`) from the payload being sent as an MMS (`image/png`).

The use of `multipart/form-data` in the fax API is specific to the way that particular metadata is included, but there isn't an equivalent system for SMS/MMS as they both need that particular meta information encoded either as a single JSON document or as the JSON element of a `multipart/mixed` message.

To send a *file*, though, `multipart/mixed` is fine. Your request would then be something like:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/403391985008/extension/403391985008/sms
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=Boundary_1_14413901_1361871080888

--Boundary_1_14413901_1361871080888
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{"to" :[{"phoneNumber": "+18772004569"},{"phoneNumber": "+18772094569"}],
"text" :"hello",
"from" :{"phoneNumber": "+18882004237"}}

--Boundary_1_14413901_1361871080888
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.zip"

[Some encoded binary stream here ...]

--Boundary_1_14413901_1361871080888--
```

It'd be up to you to set the file's mime type properly and ensure things are encoded. The key points here are that the *message* information is encoded in the first JSON component in your multipart message, while the *file* attached to the MMS is encoded in the second.