# Multipart Form - 400 Bad Request

Tags: json, automation, bad-request, ringcentral, workato

I'm having some trouble with a an API request I'm trying to make. Here is my POST request URL:

[https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/fax](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/%7E/extension/%7E/fax)

Request content type: multipart form

Header name and value:

[image]

Review:

[image]

Any idea why this may be happening? Thank you all!

Comment: were you able to solve this? I used Authorization in an app & it works fine.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2fen8Yp

Answer (score 2):

multipart/form-data can be sent as shown in the following example with image attachment:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms
Authorization: Bearer <MyToken>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=12345

--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

+16505550101
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

+16505550102
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

+16505550100
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

Hello World
--12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment" filename="picture.jpg"

content of picture.jpg ...
--12345--
```

This can be done using curl as follows:

```
curl -XPOST https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <MyToken>' \
-F 'to=+16505550101' \
-F 'to=+16505550102' \
-F 'from=+16505550100' \
-F 'text=Hello World' \
-F 'attachment=@picture.jpg'
```

**References** :

- https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/messaging/fax/fax-multipart-formats
- [Is it possible to send RingCentral SMS / MMS using multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366977/is-it-possible-to-send-ringcentral-sms-mms-using-multipart-form-data)